# Is it possible to get a gcloud build logs using api call?

Tags: api, logging, build, gcloud

Is it possible to get build logs using api call ?

gcloud builds log BUILD_ID

I have to do it using my nodejs app

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The CLI command would be of the form:

```sh
BUILD_ID=[[SOME-BUILD-ID]]
gcloud logging read "resource.type=\"build\" resource.labels.build_id=\"${BUILD_ID}\" " \
--project=${PROJECT} ...
```

**NB** If you augment the above command with the global `--log-http`, the output will include details of the underlying API methods. This is a good way to map `gcloud` commands to APIs.

The underlying API is `logging.googleapis.com/v2`

A good approach is to build the filter using Logs Viewer:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=${PROJECT}&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22build%22
```

Or, if like me, you like playing with `jq`:

```sh
BUILD_ID=...
gcloud logging read "resource.type=\"build\" resource.labels.build_id=\"${BUILD_ID}\" " \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--limit=50 \
--format="json" \
| jq -r .[].textPayload
```

You may interact with any Google API using the wonderful and understated APIs Explorer. Here's API Explorer pre-selected with logging:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/logging/logging/v2/logging.entries.list

You mentioned using Node.JS, Google provides SDKs for all its services using a bunch of popular languages and runtimes, here's a page describing the Logging API with Node.JS examples:

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs

Comment: This is an interesting direction but no concrete example in node is provided

Comment: @zaitsman if you ask your own question, I'll try to answer it.

Comment: When you use `gcloud builds log BUILD_ID --log-http`, the underlying API is build v1 API. But the logs endpoint is not documented. Doing this request takes ~1 second for me. When I try using the logging v2 api, fetching the build logs takes ~35 seconds...